# Difference between build and deploy?

Tags: deployment, build

What is the difference between a **`build and deploy`**  and **`re-deploy`**? 
What should be done when you just have some `HTML` changes and no `Java` code changes?
Should I do a **`build and deploy`** or just a **`re-deploy`**?

Comment: What technologies are you using?  JSP?  Anything dynamic?

Comment: Your question/questions are confusing, and as a result impossible to answer.  Please clarify what you are trying to compare.  A build and deploy versus simply a "patch" aka just copy the files I changed to the server.

Comment: I am using velocity templete language(VTL). My question really is When do i do a build and when do i do a redeploy. I have both option exists in my project. I am confused when should i do a a full build and when redeploy is neccesary. IN order to be in the safe side i am doing both build and redeploy.

Comment: Do the builds take a long time?

Comment: no not at all. But i have a confusion what is the difference in building and deploying a project

Comment: @FirstHearty those are relative terms, meaning they can vary depending on a companies practices.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**Disclaimer**:  Defining what build and deploy means is very subjective.

---

I will start with deploy. Deploy should mean take all of my artifacts and either copy them to a server, or execute them on a server. It should truly be a simple process.

Build means, process all of my code/artifacts and prepare them for deployment. Meaning compile, generate code, package, etc.

That helped? Some people do consider deploy as part of the "build process" which I don't really argue with because generally in order to test or run you have to deploy it *somewhere*.

---

The rule is generally if it is dynamic code, then you need to do a build/redeploy.

If you are just editing static html, css, images etc. then you can simply just patch (and preferably a server restart).

---

As always when "patching" there is added risk that you could not be deploying the entire code base, or someone could do it wrong.

Personally I like doing full build/redeploys because you always know you are in-sync with your source control.  However there is always risk that deployments go bad, either the build part or the install part.  If your builds take a long time, or you are  unnecessarily having to deploy a lot of moving parts, then consider either breaking them down into smaller deployable components or create a more complete deployment plan.

As usual there is no silver bullet here.

Answer (score 29):

**Build** means to **Compile the project**.

**Deploy** means to **Compile the project & Publish the output**

1. For web applications no need to deploy or nothing need to do at client side except simple browser with url.
   all web applications are deployed at Server Machine(IIS) only, that application can be accessed by all client machines (any browser is enough).
2. For Desktop applications Wherever you want to use the application, need to deployed/installed in that system.

Answer (score 2):

Watch this deploying process:

```
------ Build started: Project: AdventureWorks, Configuration: Release ------
Skipping 'belyaev_db.rds'. Item is up to date.
Skipping 'Sales Rep.rdl'. Item is up to date.
Skipping 'Top_10.rsd'. Item is up to date.
Build complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings

------ Deploy started: Project: AdventureWorks, Configuration: Release ------
Deploying to http://...
Deploying data source '/Data Sources/belyaev_db'.
Warning : ...
Deploying data set '/Datasets/Top_10'.
Warning : ...
Error ...
Deploy complete -- 1 errors, 2 warnings
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

In this case I have some issues but as you can see - first step is in building - verification data sources and reports and only after that - deploying.

Answer (score 1):

Build and Deployment are Back To Back Processes!
**Build** can be taken **Only if** there is any **JAVA Code Change**.
For only HTML or CSS file updates, no need of New Build.
*The Property files change needs the Server Restart.*

*No need of Deploying Unchanged Build ear/tar file.* 
For updated ear Build, Deployment on Server process should be initiated.

Answer (score 0):

The gist:

```
  SOURCE DEPLOYMENT MODEL
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                      │
│                       BINARY DEPLOYMENT MODEL                        │
│                     ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────┐  │
│                     │                                             │  │
│                     │                                             │  │
│  ┌────────┐         │  ┌─────────────┐           ┌─────────────┐  │  │
│  │ source │  BUILD  │  │ application │  DELIVER  │  installed  │  │  │
│  │  code  ├─────────┼─►│   binary    ├──────────►│ application │  │  │
│  └────────┘         │  └─────────────┘           └─────────────┘  │  │
│                     │                                             │  │
│                     │                                             │  │
│                     └─────────────────────────────────────────────┘  │
│                                                                      │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

To put it in context:

```
  BINARY DEPLOYMENT MODEL
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│                BUILD MACHINE                                                 │
│                 ( OR FARM )                             TARGET MACHINE       │
│    ______________________________________            _____________________   │
│   /                                     /│          /                    /│  │
│  ┌─────────────────────────────────────┐ │         ┌────────────────────┐ │  │
│  │                                     │ │         │                    │ │  │
│  │ ┌────────┐          ┌─────────────┐ │ │         │   ┌─────────────┐  │ │  │
│  │ │ source │  BUILD   │ application │ │ │ DELIVER │   │  installed  │  │ │  │
│  │ │  code  ├─────────►│   binary    ├─┼─┼─────────┼──►│ application │  │ │  │
│  │ └────────┘          └─────────────┘ │ │         │   └─────────────┘  │ │  │
│  │                                     │/          │                    │/   │
│  └─────────────────────────────────────┘           └────────────────────┘    │
│                                                                              │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

```
  SOURCE DEPLOYMENT MODEL
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                               │
│     BUILD MACHINE                                                             │
│      ( OR FARM )                                  TARGET MACHINE              │
│   _______________              _____________________________________________  │
│  /              /│            /                                            /│ │
│ ┌──────────────┐ │           ┌────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │ │
│ │              │ │           │                                            │ │ │
│ │  ┌────────┐  │ │           │   ┌─────────────┐         ┌─────────────┐  │ │ │
│ │  │ source │  │ │  DELIVER  │   │ application │  BUILD  │  installed  │  │ │ │
│ │  │  code  ├──┼─┼───────────┼──►│   binary    ├────────►│ application │  │ │ │
│ │  └────────┘  │ │           │   └─────────────┘         └─────────────┘  │ │ │
│ │              │/            │                                            │/  │
│ └──────────────┘             └────────────────────────────────────────────┘   │
│                                                                               │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```