# What is a Docker build stage?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

As far as I understand build stages in Docker are fundamental things, and I have a practical understanding of them but I have trouble coming up with a proper definition, and I also can't seem to find one.

So: what is the definition of a Docker **build stage**?

Edit: I'm **not** asking "how do I use a build stage?" or "how can I use multi-build stages?" which people seem very eager to answer :-)

The reason I have this question is because I saw the following sentences in [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from):

- "The FROM instruction initializes a new build stage"
- "a name can be given to a new build stage"

Which left me wondering: what exactly *is* a build stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there will ever be a strict definition for ***Docker build stage*** because a build stage is in general something theoretical which:

- can be defined by you
- depends on your case (language / libraries)

---

In this question: [Difference between build and deploy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427679/difference-between-build-and-deploy) one of the answers says...

> **Build** means to **Compile the project**.

I think you can see it this way too. A ***build stage*** is any procedure that *generates* something which can later be taken and used.

---

The idea with docker *multi-stage* builds is to:

1. generate what you are going to need
2. leave behind what you don't need and use the product of step 1 in a more lightweight way

If you have read the docs, Alex Ellis has a nice example where the same logic takes place:

1. he starts with a `golang` image, adds libraries, builds his app (Go generates a binary executable file)
2. after that, he doesn't need golang and the libraries to ship/run it so, he picks an `alpine` image, adds the executable file from step 1 and ships his app with an image that has much smaller size.

Comment: OK, so I think the answer to my question is in your sentence: "A build stage is any procedure that generates something". It's quite a generic answer, but I think it's good enough.

The part about multi-stage builds is, for my question, irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

A stage is the creation an image. In a multi-stage build, you go through the process of creating more than one image, however you typically only tag a single one (exceptions being multiple builds, building a multi-architecture image manifest with a tool like buildx, and anything else docker releases after this answer).

---

Each stage, building a distinct image, starts from a `FROM` line in the Dockerfile. One stage doesn't inherit anything done in previous stages, it is based on its own base image. So if you have the following:

```
FROM alpine as stage1
RUN apk add your_tool

FROM alpine as stage2
RUN your_tool some args
```

you will get an error since `your_tool` is not installed in the second stage.

---

Which stage do you get as output from the build? By default the last stage, but you can change that with the `docker image build --target stage1 .` to build the stage with the name, `stage1` in this example. The classic docker build will run from the top of the Dockerfile until if finishes the target stage. Buildkit builds a dependency graph and builds stages concurrently and only if needed, so do not depend on this ordering to control something like a testing workflow in your Dockerfile (buildkit can see if nothing in the test stage is needed in your release stage and skip building the test).

---

What's the value of multiple stages? Typically, its done to separate the build environment from the runtime environment. It allows you to perform the entire build inside of docker. This has two advantages.

First, you don't require an external Makefile and various compilers and other tools installed on the host to compile the binaries that then get copied into the image with a `COPY` line, anyone with docker can build your image.

And second, the resulting image doesn't include all the compilers or other build time tooling that isn't needed at runtime, resulting in smaller and more secure images. The typical example is a java app with maven and a full JDK to build, a runtime with just the jar file and the JRE.

---

If each stage makes a separate image, how do you get the jar file from the build stage to the run stage? That comes from a new option to the `COPY` command, `--from`. An oversimplified multi-stage build looks like:

```
FROM maven as build
COPY src /app/src
WORKDIR /app/src
RUN mvn install

FROM openjdk:jre as release
COPY --from=build /app/src/target/app.jar /app
CMD java -jar /app/app.jar
```

With that `COPY --from=build` we are able to take the artifact built in the build stage and add it to the release stage, without including anything else from that first stage (no layers of compile tools like JDK or Maven get added to our second stage).

---

How is the `FROM x as y` and the `COPY --from=y /a /b` working together? The `FROM x as y` is defining an image name for the duration of this build, in this case `y`. Anywhere later in the Dockerfile that you would put an image name, you can put `y` and you'll get the result of this stage as your input. So you could say:

```
FROM upstream as mybuilder
RUN apk add common_tools

FROM mybuilder as stage2
RUN some_tool arg2

FROM mybuilder as stage3
RUN some_tool arg3

FROM minimal_base as release
COPY --from=stage2 /bin2 /
COPY --from=stage3 /bin3 /
```

Note how `stage2` and `stage3` are each `FROM mybuilder` that is the output of the first stage.

The `COPY --from=y` allows you to change the context where you are copying from to be another image instead of the build context. It doesn't have to be another stage. So, for example, you could do the following to get a docker binary in your image:

```
FROM alpine
COPY --from=docker:stable /usr/local/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/
```

---

Further documentation on this is available at: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Answer (score 2):

Since version 17, `docker` now supports multiple stages during a `docker build` executions.

This means, that you no longer need to define only one source image in your docker file and do the whole build in a single run, but you can define multiple stages with different images in your `Dockerfile` for each stage with multiple `FROM` definitions:

```
# Build stage
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
# ..do a build with a dev image for creating ./app artifact

# Publish - use a hardened, production image
FROM alpine:latest
CMD ["./app"]
```

This gives you the benefit to break your image building process to be optimized for a task that you are doing in a stage - for example the stages could be:

1. use an image with extra linting dependencies to check your source
2. use a dev-image with all development dependencies already installed to build your source
3. use another image including test frameworks to run various tests on the artifacts
4. and once everything passed ok, use a minimal-sized, optimized, hardened image to capture the final artifacts for production

Read more in details about `multistage-build`:

- https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: Thanks. And I understand how multiple-build-stages work. That still does not answer my question: what *is* a build stage?

Answer (score 1):

a build stage starts at a FROM statement and ends at the step before the next FROM statement

Answer (score 0):

> **stage** | steɪdʒ |
>   *noun*
>   a point, period, or step in a process or development

Take a practical example: you want to build an image which contains a production ready web server with Typescript files compiled to Javascript. You want to build that Typescript within a Docker container to simplify dependency management. So you need:

- node.js
- Typescript
- any dependencies needed for compilation
- Webpack or whatever
- nginx/Apache/whatever

In your final image you only really need the compiled .js files and, say, nginx. But to get there, you need all that other stuff first. When you upload that final image, it will contain all the intermediate layers, even if they're unnecessary for the final product.

Docker build stages now allow you to actually separate those *stages*, or *steps*, into separate images, while still using just one Dockerfile and not needing to glue several Dockerfiles together with external shell scripts or such. E.g.:

```
FROM node as builder
RUN npm install ...
# whatever you need to build your files

FROM nginx as production
COPY --from=builder /final.js /var/www/html
```

The final result of this Dockerfile is a small image with `nginx` as its base plus just the final .js file. It does not contain all the unnecessary stuff like node.js and the npm dependencies.

**`builder`** here is the first **stage**, **`production`** is the second **stage**. In this case the first stage will be discarded at the end of the process, but you can also choose to build a specific stage using `docker build --target=builder`. A new `FROM` introduces a new, separate stage. They're essentially separate Dockerfiles, but they can share data using `COPY --from`.

Comment: You're not wrong :-) And you're basically giving the same answer as @muratiakos; explaining how multistage-builds work and why they are useful. And: you're also not giving a **definition** of what a build stage is, just how to use them.

Comment: How much more defined can it get? I am defining the word "stage" and I am describing how it applies to the Docker build process. What other kind of definition do you expect?

Comment: More. I know the meaning of the word stage in English. I don't know the meaning of the word "build stage" in the Docker context. And as I stated in my question: I know how to use them, just not what the definition for one is.

I think @tgogos' answer was better.